# How to read gpio current mode in shell or wiringpi

Tags: raspbian, gpio, wiringpi

I am trying to find out if a specific GPIO is set on `OUT` or `IN`
I need something similar to this php command `exec ("gpio read ".$i, $val_array[$i], $return );`
but instead of returning `LOW` or `HIGH` (0 or 1) in the case of wiringpi, i need it to return out or in. as a variable/

(real beginner here)
Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[pigpio](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/index.html) offers a method to read the GPIO mode from C, Python, and the shell.

- C http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/cif.html#gpioGetMode
- Python http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/python.html#get_mode
- shell http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/pigs.html#MG/MODEG

From the shell use `pigs`, e.g. `pigs mg 4` will return the mode of GPIO 4 (assuming that the pigpio daemon is running (`sudo pigpiod`)).

The returned value is as follows.

```
Value     0     1      2    3    4    5    6    7
Mode    Input Output ALT5 ALT4 ALT0 ALT1 ALT2 ALT3
```

Comment: Thanks @joan, that seems pretty straightforward. Works well. Could i have a quick input on how to set the pigpiod to run on startup and reboot? (as i said, total beginner here)

Comment: @krasatos `sudo systemctl enable pigpiod` will start the pigpio daemon at boot.

Comment: Thanks a ton, works as a charm, you saved me a lot of time!

Comment: Is there a way to use `pigs` with the `wPi` numbering instead of the `bcm`? Or do i have to translate the numbers?

Comment: @krasatos No, pigpio only uses (Broadcom) GPIO numbers.

Comment: @krasatos I'd personally recommend just sticking with the GPIO scheme. It's by far the most widely used, and almost all code examples everywhere typically use it. I've found that the vast majority of the time when someone says "pin 18", they mean GPIO pin #18 (physical 12). I've written a Perl wrapper around wiringPi. At first, I supported all pin schemes. After a while, I decided to hide all modes except for GPIO (it's there, but no longer advertised) for simplicity's sake.

Comment: Thanks for the input @stevieb. Glad you suggested this while I'm still young on the RPi. I'll get used to it. BTW, by gpios you mean BCM right?

Comment: Yes, BCM (aka Broadcom), that's correct. They are also the ones printed conveniently on most breadboard breakout connectors.